# how to log to app insights from .net core 6

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights

I have a solution with 2 projects:

1. function app project
2. web api .net core 6.0 project

The function app is succesfully logging to app insights, but the web api project is not! Azure portal is showing that both of the projects are configured to write to the same instance of app insights.

**Is it a problem that two different  resources are writing to the same app insights instance? If not, what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: ill post 500 bounty if needed

Comment: you have this much reputation, then you should know that any kind of code, showing what you have done, goes a long way ;)

Comment: and no, this is no problem "Is it a problem that two different resources are writing to the same app insights instance? "

Comment: In a web api project when setting up DI you may need to initialize telemetry by calling services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(<youroptionshere>), and for logging services.AddLogging(config => config.AddApplicationInsights(<yourkeyhere>)): I have several projects writing to the same instance in AI and its working fine.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem in connecting the same app insights instance with 2 different resources

Comment: looking for general guidance on how to troubleshoot this. all the configuration settings seem to be standardly configured

Comment: @AnthonyG. thank you that did it! feel free to make it the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To configure Application Insights with telemetry you need to configure both telemetry and logging independently. Manual configuration or convention based in config configuration can both be used:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcore6

Manually setting options when configuring DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)
{
    // ...
    ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions telemetryOptions = new ();
telemetryOptions.InstrumentationKey = YourInstrumentationKey;

    // Can enable/disable adaptive sampling here.
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling
    telemetryOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(telemetryOptions);

    services.AddLogging(logBuilder =>
             {
                 logBuilder.AddApplicationInsights(YourInstrumentationKey)
                     // adding custom filter for specific use case. 
                     .AddFilter("Orleans", (level) => level == LogLevel.Error);
    });
    // ...
}
```

When using `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "Copy connection string from Application Insights Resource Overview"
  }
}
```

Then DI is can be slightly simplified:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)
{
    // ...
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    services.AddLogging(logBuilder => logBuilder.AddApplicationInsights()});
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Note that using InstrumentationKey directly is not recommended and obsolete. MSFT recommends using App Insight Connection String.

Comment: Can I use Serilog with this setup?