# How to enable Application Insights for a windows service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, azure-application-insights

I have a windows service in which the `Program.cs` is like this -

```
 static class Program
    {
    static void Main()
            {
                var serviceBases = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                    new RetrievalService(), 
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(serviceBases);
            }
    }
```

The `RetrievalService` class is as follows:

```
public partial class RetrievalService: ServiceBase
    {
        
        public RetrievalService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

I added the NugetPackage - `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` in the project and I do have the AppInsight `InstrumentationKey`. I tried creating a Telemetry in the Main class and adding the `InstrumentationKey` to configure it, but all APIs in the Nuget is related to ServiceCollection (for Web Api) but could not add for ServiceBase. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74435918/how-to-log-to-app-insights-from-net-core-6#74436360 this would do it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core shows the new package setup and configuration

Comment: @AnthonyG. No. This doesnt work because my Main program has ServiceBase and not IServiceCollection, So, I am not able to configure logging like this - services.AddLogging as shown in your example

Comment: I think you are missing the point of using DI to configure and setup your dependencies. The links were provided as a general guide, not a copy and paste solution to just work for your use-case. You inheriting from ServiceBase makes no difference, you will still need to configure and inject a logger or telemetryclient. Just about all of Microsoft's modern Nuget packages require and document the use of good IOC principles. ServiceCollection is the implementation used in Web API's, while IServiceProvider would provide same functionality in your console/service code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Serilog. 
Install nuget package `Serilog` `Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights`

RetrievalService.cs

```
    public partial class RetrievalService : ServiceBase
    {
        public RetrievalService()
        {
            ServiceName = "Retrieval";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Information("retrieval starting...");
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Log.Fatal("retrieval stopped!");
        }
    }
```

LoggerService.cs

```
    public class LoggerService : ServiceBase
    {
        public LoggerService()
        {
            ServiceName = "Logger";

            var connectionString = "InstrumentationKey=xxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=xxx/;LiveEndpoint=hxx";
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(connectionString, TelemetryConverter.Traces)
            .CreateLogger();
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
var serviceBases = new ServiceBase[] {
    new RetrievalService(), 
    new LoggerService()
};
ServiceBase.Run(serviceBases);
```

Create a service
`sc create TestService binPath=D:\TESTS\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\bin\Release\net6.0\ConsoleApp3.exe`
Test if start the service.
[image]
The problem is when you stop the service process. It won't be logged. Loggers to keep alive the the process. But when service process is terminated, it won't work.

Only if you stop inside the program ,it could be logged, because the windows service process is still on.

```
var retrievalSerivce = serviceBases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ServiceName == "Retrieval");
retrievalSerivce.Stop();
ServiceBase.Run(retrievalSerivce);
```

[image]